# Draggable border like Leetcode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to make a border like Leetcode where i can adjust left and right containers. I have googled but I could find much about my problem.[image]

I have the following code

```
const divider = document.getElementById('divider');
  const [divPosition, setDivPosition] = useState(window.innerWidth - 700);


useEffect(() => {
    function resize(e: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(e.x);
      const dx = window.innerWidth - e.x;
      console.log(dx);
      setDivPosition(e.x);
      // if (divider) divider.style.width = dx + 'px';
    }
    if (divider)
      divider?.addEventListener(
        'mousedown',
        (e) => {
          if (e.offsetX < 6) {
            logger(e.x, String(e.offsetX));
            // setDivPosition(e.offsetX);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize, false);
          }
        },
        false
      );
    document.addEventListener(
      'mouseup',
      function () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize, false);
      },
      false
    );

    return () => {
      if (divider)
        divider.removeEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
          if (e.offsetX < 6) {
            logger(e.offsetX, 'offset is');
            // logger(e.x, String(e.offsetX));
            // setDivPosition(e.offsetX);
            // document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize, false);
          }
        });
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [divider]);
```

But it has delays and more I resize slower it gets and border gets behind mouse. Moreover, when I click and start to resize, cursor changes to normal cursor.

How can I make it exactly like leetcode's? and any resources?

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a great answer for y problem: [Split.js](https://split.js.org/)